# How do you graph ω² in a Bode Plot?

Tags: bode-plot

Assume this transfer function. How would you graph \$\omega^2\$?

[image]

Apparently, the solution just says you would graph 0.1 by itself for a -20 dB curve. Could someone explain? I also have a screenshot of the magnitude Bode Plots which I am not understanding where w^2 is factored in. Thank you

[image: bode plot]

Comment: \$\omega^2\$ is a real number, and equal to \$\left(2\pi f\right)^2 \$.

Comment: ... and the x axis of a bode plot is frequency, not magnitude

Comment: Log (X^2) = 2*Log X... so it has twice the slope.

Comment: \$\omega^2\$ is a line of slope 40 dB/decade passing through \$\omega=1\$; 0.1 is a line with zero gradient at -20 dB. The \$\omega^2\$ line is not in your plot.

Comment: It's far easier to leave the TF in Laplace form to do the plot. The \$ j\omega 's\$ everywhere just clutter things up

Comment: @Chu, you need to convert Laplace to Fourier to compute a bode plot using numerical approaches, as opposed to just ID'ing corners, as s is complex.

Comment: thanks for the help. It appears that it was not expressed in the solution plot, which was very confusing to me

Comment: @Scott Seidman, I read the question as implying asymptotic construction.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold, so 40dB/Decade, passing through -40dB at \$\omega\$=0.1

Answer (score 1):

You just calculate it and plot it:

In Matlab:

```
>> w=logspace( -1 , 10,10000);
>> xfun = .1*w.^2.*(1 - (w./10).^2 +j*w./2)./((1+j.*w).*(1+j.*w/100).^3);
>> subplot(2,1,1)
>> semilogx(w, 20*log10(abs(xfun)))
>> subplot(2,1,2)
>> semilogx(w, angle(xfun)*180/pi)][1]][1]
```

[image]

You could just use "bode", but that's easier w/ the Laplace transform.  Because I didn't, the x-axes are in radians, with no labels.  I adjusted the line widths and font sizes for export to a jpg.

If you don't have Matlab, this should work directly in Octave, which is free.  If the freq scale is off, feel free to adjust w.  If you want freq in Hz, remember that \$\omega=2\pi f\$

As a tip, remember that your exponents need to be ".^", not "^", and your multiplies and divides need to be ".*" and "./" -- all for element-by-element operations.

If you're just interested in \$\omega^2\$, \$20log_{10}\omega^2 = 40log_{10}\omega\$.  At \$\omega=0.1\$, this is equal to -40dB, and it will have a slope of 40db/decade.  Perhaps even more intuitively, it is 0dB at \$\omega=1\$.  It is real, so the angle is 0.

```
>> w=logspace( -1 , 10,10000);
>> w2=w.^2;
>> subplot(2,1,1)
>> semilogx(w, 20*log10(abs(w2)))
>> subplot(2,1,2)
>> semilogx(w, angle(w2))
```

[image]

This, of course gives you 80dB/decade total going up, above 100 rad/sec, and 80 going down, for a flat line.

Comment: its even easier than that in matlab.

Comment: @JonRB,  yes --  with the right toolboxes, and then it's less instructive.   Being able to do something and knowing what you're doing are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

For a Bode plot you usually either \$ f \$ (frequency in Hz) or \$ \omega \$ (frequency in rad/sec) on the x-axis and Magnitude (in dB) and Phase (in degrees) on the y-axis.

As such you don't plot \$ \omega^2 \$ on a bode plot but the Magnitude and phase you calculate from the transfer function. Remembering that if you are plotting against frequency (in Hz) \$ \omega^2 = (2 \pi f)^2 = 4 \pi^2 f^2 \$

Remembering that this is arithmetic using complex numbers.